# How to set svg size to fit its content?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

the content of my SVG is depending on width/height of device. there are multi elements and I cannot calculate the content of it.
now How I can set the width/height if svg depending on the content?

```
      <Svg
        ref="circleslider"
        width={?}
        height={?}
        style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>
           .. my elemetns
```

updated
full code:

```
return (

  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

    <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: ((width) / 2), justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
    >

      <Svg
        ref="circleslider"
        width={width}
        height={width}
        style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>

      <Circle
          cx={(width) / 2}
          cy={(width) / 2}
          r="140"
          fill="#f9ebea"
          {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}
        />

      <Circle
          cx={(width) / 2}
          cy={(width) / 2}
          r="120"
          fill="#f9e1e1"
          {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}
        />

        <Circle
          cx={(width) / 2}
          cy={(width) / 2}
          r="100"
          fill="#f9dbd9"
          {...this._panResponderTwo.panHandlers}
        />



        <Circle
          cx={(width) / 2}
          cy={(width) / 2}
          r={this.props.diameterCenter}
          fill="#fff"
        />

        {/* <Image
            x={((heightDevice) / 4) - (imageWidth/8)}
            y={((widthDevice) / 4) - (imageWidth/8)}
            r={this.props.diameterCenter}
            width={imageWidth}
            height={imageHeight}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            opacity="0.5"
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            href={require('../../../images/ics/home/ic_center.png')}
            clipPath="url(#clip)" /> */}



        <G x={bankingservicesCoord.x - widthHeight} y={bankingservicesCoord.y - widthHeight}
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

          {(moveed == 'bankingservices') ?
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill={selectedItemColor}
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderBankingServices.panHandlers}
              />
            )
            :
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill="#fff"
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderBankingServices.panHandlers}
              />
            )
          }

          <Image
            x={imageX}
            y={imageY}
            width={imageWidth}
            height={imageHeight}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            opacity="0.5"
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            href={require('../../../images/ics/home/ic_bank.png')}
            clipPath="url(#clip)"
            {...this._panResponderBankingServices.panHandlers} />

        </G>

        <G x={shopsCoord.x - widthHeight} y={shopsCoord.y - widthHeight}>

          {(moveed == 'shops') ?
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill={selectedItemColor}
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderShops.panHandlers}
              />
            )
            :
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill="#fff"
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderShops.panHandlers}
              />
            )
          }


          <Image
            x={imageX}
            y={imageY}
            width={imageWidth}
            height={imageHeight}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            opacity="0.5"
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            href={require('../../../images/ics/home/ic_shop.png')}
            clipPath="url(#clip)"
            {...this._panResponderShops.panHandlers} />

        </G>

        <G x={locationsCoord.x - widthHeight} y={locationsCoord.y - widthHeight}>

          {(moveed == 'location') ?
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill={selectedItemColor}
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderLocations.panHandlers}
              />
            )
            :
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill="#fff"
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderLocations.panHandlers}
              />
            )
          }

          <Image
            x={imageX}
            y={imageY}
            width={imageWidth}
            height={imageHeight}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            opacity="0.5"
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            href={require('../../../images/ics/home/ic_location.png')}
            clipPath="url(#clip)"
            {...this._panResponderLocations.panHandlers} />

        </G>

        <G x={kasianserviceCoord.x - widthHeight} y={kasianserviceCoord.y - widthHeight}>


          {(moveed == 'kasianservices') ?
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill={selectedItemColor}
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderKasianServices.panHandlers}
              />
            )
            :
            (
              <Circle
                r={widthHeight}
                cx={widthHeight}
                cy={widthHeight}
                fill="#fff"
                stroke={selectedItemColor}
                {...this._panResponderKasianServices.panHandlers}
              />
            )
          }

          <Image
            x={imageX}
            y={imageY}
            width={imageWidth}
            height={imageHeight}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            opacity="0.5"
            style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
            href={require('../../../images/ics/home/ic_kasian.png')}
            clipPath="url(#clip)"
            {...this._panResponderKasianServices.panHandlers} />
        </G>


      </Svg>


    </View>


  </View>
)
```

Comment: may be this can help: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/

Comment: I have read the question 3 times now. I still have no idea what your trying to do. What do you mean by "cannot calculate the content of it". You don't need to calculate width height of an svg. Since its by default responsive. You should define a viewBox attribute on the svg.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the height / width of the svg as inline css style within the `style` attribute:

```
<Svg
    ref="circleslider"
    style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '100px', height: '100px' }}>
```

Comment: You cannot remove width and height attribute from SVG.

Comment: I didn't get it. You mean I shouldn't remove or it's invalid ? I have svg elements in my projects working without those attributes and I can easily add css styles to them, (not all the css property works on them though)
I might need to see the SVG element, is it possible to share ?

Comment: Or if you have the flexibility to not use the `svg` you can use `img`, `object` or even an `iframe` to display the `svg` and apply css styles to make it responsive however you want

Comment: I post whole my code. when I remove width and height, I get error.

Comment: I see, the `width` value seems to be a variable declared somewhere else and it's being used multiple times there. do you know what  value does that evaluate ?

Comment: Also, do you want the `svg` to be responsive according to display size ? or you need the inner elements of the svg to be inside the main svg element ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand.  I am going to assume that you want the SVG to scale to fit it's parent view.  Is that correct?

If so, you probably want to do something like this:

```
  <Svg
    ref="circleslider"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 {width} {width}">
```

Comment: `I am going to assume that you want the SVG to scale to fit it's parent view. Is that correct?` Yes.